# ESP8266 module publishes messages but the subscriber doesn't get anything via MQTT

Tags: node.js, tcp, mqtt, microcontroller, iot

I am a newbie in IoT and MQTT. I have a ESP8266 module that wants to connect to a web app and publish messages to it, for doing this I am using pubsub client library for the module and NodeJs MQTT for the server-side and HiveMQ.com as a broker.
The module can publish messages randomly successfully but the subscriber(server-side) can't get any messages. What's the problem?

**Module**

```
const char* ssid = "Knight";
const char* password = "0520298926";
const char* mqtt_server = "broker.hivemq.com";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
unsigned long lastMsg = 0;
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE  (50)
char msg[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "clientId-xnHbRALbr5";
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("doorphone/connected", "true");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("doorphone/close");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {

  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();

//  unsigned long now = millis();
// 
//    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, MSG_BUFFER_SIZE, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("doorphone/open", msg);

}
```

**Server-Side**

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
var options = [{
    port: 1883,
    host: 'mqtt://broker.hivemq.com',
    clientId: '',
}];
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com', options)

/**
* The state of the doorphone, defaults to closed
* Possible states : closed, opening, open, closing
*/


client.on('connect', () => {
  client.subscribe('doorphone/open')
  client.subscribe('doorphone/close')

  // Inform controllers that doorphone is connected
  client.subscribe('doorphone/connected', 'true')
})

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    console.log('received message %s %s', topic, message)
    switch (topic) {
        case 'doorphone/open':
          return handleOpenRequest(message)
        case 'doorphone/close':
          return handleCloseRequest(message)
        case 'doorphone/connected':
            console.log(message)
      }
})


function handleOpenRequest (message) {
    console.log('opening doorphone door %s', message)
}


function handleCloseRequest (message) {
    console.log('closing doorphone door %s', message)
}
```

Comment: You can use any MQTT publisher client to test your subscriber. That will narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @GambitSupport Subscriber is working OK

Comment: How do you know "The module can publish messages randomly successfully" if there is no error handling in your code??? The ONLY way to know that the publish actually gets to the broker is to have debug output from the broker, eg. mosquitto -v

Comment: I hope that `052*******` isn't your phone number otherwise: it seems wise to remove it.

Comment: @Tarick Thanks for your advice; No it's no a valuable number